# Microsoft Exchange Server no longer updates via WiFi after upgrading to Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, exchange

I had my Samsung Galaxy Note 4 (as well as several other Samsung devices - such as two tablets) set up to sync with my Microsoft Exchange Server all without problems before upgrading to Android Lollipop. After upgrading to Lollipop, I am no longer able to sync (refresh) via wifi.

How to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-adding the accounts?

Comment: re-adding the accounts does not work!

Answer (score 0):

You have to erase the proxy number in the APN network. This is something that Lollipop retrieves from your Data provider, but trunks the communication with the server.

Comment: I have no idea how to go about erasing the proxy number in the APN network?